# show a mapping is open by considering only subbasic elements

Tags: general-topology

Let  $(X,\tau),(Y,\sigma)$ be topological spaces and $\mathfrak{S}$ be a subbasis for $\tau$.

I am looking for additional assumptions that make the following statement true:

> The mapping $f$ is open iff $f(S) \in \sigma$ for all $S \in \mathfrak{S}$.

A counterexample showing that this is not possible without further assumptions is the following:

Consider $$X:=\{1,2,3\},\,
\tau:=\{\emptyset,\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{2\},X\}$$ with subbasis $$\mathfrak{S}:=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$$
and $Y = \{0,1\}$ with $\sigma := \{\emptyset, Y\}$.

Then consider the characteristic function $\chi_{\{2\}}$.

Comment: Assume that $f$ is injective.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  Nice. This allows me to use $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$! With $f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$ this gives the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't generally work (as in your counterexample) is that the direct image of a function needn't preserve intersections. It does preserve arbitrary unions though, so the intersections are the only thing you need to check.

Thus one sufficient condition is that $f$ preserves at least finite intersections. This is equivalent to assuming that $f$ is injective, and hence preserves all intersections. Alternatively, you could consider the somewhat apparently weaker assumption that $f$ preserves finite intersections of subbasis open sets. If $X$ is Hausdorff, this is again equivalent to assuming $f$ is injective.