# Ultrafilter-compact subspaces of Hausdorff spaces are not necessarily closed

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I am trying to follow a proof in Herrlich's *Axiom of Choice*:

[image]

Currently, I am trying to prove the highlighted sentence. For $f$ to be an embedding it has to be a homeomorphism of $P$ onto $f(P)$.

I have already been able to show that $f$ is injective and am trying to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

At first I thought, there could be an generalization of the classical theorem for compact spaces

> $f \colon X \to Y$, continuous, invertible, X is compact and Y is Hausdorff then $f^{-1}$ is continuous

but there isn't. The fact that compact subspaces of Hausdorff spaces are closed is crucial for this proof and won't hold for ultrafilter-compact spaces (this is in fact a conclusion to be drawn from the excerpt I posted)

Another characterization of homeomorphisms is, that they are bijective, continuous and open/closed mappings. Here is an idea:

Based on my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605466/show-a-mapping-is-open-by-considering-only-subbasis-elements), it suffices to consider subbasic elements of $2^I$. Let $O$ be such an element, i.e.

$$ O = \prod_{i \in I} O_i$$

with $O_i = \mathbf{2}$ for all $i \in I \setminus \{i_0\}$ and $O_{i_0} = \{1\}$. $O$ is clopen.

Suppose $O \in \mathcal{F}$. This implies that $f_O(O) = 1$. The set

$$U = \prod_{A \in X} U_A$$

with $U_A = \mathbf{2}$ for all $A \in X \setminus \{O\}$ and $U_O = \{1\}$ is open in $\mathbf{2}^X$ hence $f(O) = U \cap f(P)$.

Is this correct? What about the case where $O \not\in \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: how are the topologies on $P$ and $2^{X}$ defined?

Comment: @user159517 product topology, I suppose.

Comment: I' dont fully understand the definition of $f$. Could you write down $f$ explicitly?

Comment: @user159517: $f \colon P \to 2^X, \quad x \mapsto (f_A(x))_{A \in X}$, where $X$ is the set of all clopen subsets of $P$ contained in the filter $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Just because all your recent questions are sourced from Herrlich's book The Axiom of Choice does not mean that they are really questions related to the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Sorry, for misusing the tag. Won't happen again.

Comment: It's fine, not harm was done. Just try to see if your question is *really* about the axiom of choice, or about proofs *from* The Axiom of Choice by Herrlich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for all $A \in X$, where $X$ is a clopen member of $\mathcal{F}$, $\pi_A(f(x)) = f_A(x)$, where the latter is the characteristic function of $A$. And $P = 2^I$.
So clearly $f$ is continuous, as the composition with any projection is continuous (as $A$ is clopen, $f_A$ is continuous), using the universal property for product topologies. So the same holds for $f$ considered as a function from $P$ onto $f[P]$.

If $x \neq y$, then there is a clopen subset $F_x$ in $\mathcal{F}$ such that $x \notin F_x$ (or $x$ would be in the intersection of all such $F$ etc.). Also there is a clopen set $C$ such that $y \in C$, $x \notin C$, as $P = 2^I$ is zero-dimensional. Then define $F = C \cup F_x$. Then $x \notin F$, $y \in F$, $F$ is clopen (union of two clopens), $F \in \mathcal{F}$, as the smaller $F_x$ is. So $\pi_F(f(x)) = 0, \pi_F(f(y)) = 1$, so $f(x) \neq f(y)$. hence $f$ is 1-1.

Consider $O = (\pi_{i_0})^{-1}[\{j\}]$, a subbasic open set of $P$, where $i_0 \in I, j \in \{0,1\}$. If $O \in \mathcal{F}$, then $O \in X$ and for every $x \in O$, $\pi_O(f(x)) = 1$, so $f[O] = (\pi_O)^{-1}[\{1\}] \cap f[P]$, making $f[O]$ open in $f[P]$.

If $O \notin \mathcal{F}$, then either every $F \in \mathcal{F}$ intersects $O$, or at least one $F' \in \mathcal{F}$ misses $O$. In the latter case $F' \subseteq P \setminus O$, and we have the same argument for $P \setminus O$ which then is a member of $X$ (being clopen and in $\mathcal{F}$). So we can in the final case assume all $F \in \mathcal{F}$ intersect $O$ and also intersect $P \setminus O$. But then $f[O] = f[P]$, also open in $f[P]$, trivially.

(in short, if $O$ or its complement are in the filter, then $f[O]$ is a relative subbasic element corresponding to the set in the filter, otherwise it intersects both and $f[O] = f[P]$)

Then the remark about injective functions preserving finite intersections makes sure the images of basic elements from $P$  are open in $f[P]$, and so $f$ is open from $P$ onto $f[P]$, conclusing the proof.